# How to get product variations only if the parent product is published

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

I made a custom query to get the products variations, but when I trash a product, it's variations status will remain `publish`, so it will respond a `404` error if the customer tried to view the trashed product variations.
So, how I can filter these variations to get only the variations that have published parent product?

My code:

```
<?php  
$args = ['post_type'  => ['product_variation'],  
            'orderby'    => 'meta_value_num',
            'order'      => 'DESC',
            'post_status'=>'publish',
            'product_type'=>'variation',
            'meta_query' => [
                [
                    'key'     => 'attribute_pa_flower-type',
                    'value'   => $flower_type,
                    'compare' => '=',
                ]
            ]
        ];
?>

<?php $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );?>

<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

    <div class="boxes">
        <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
        ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do some thing like this:

```
//to hold the published product id which has vriation.
$has_variable_ids = [];

$args_parent = [
    'post_type' => ['product'],
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1
];

$pubished_post = new WP_Query($args_parent);
if (!empty($pubished_post->posts))
{
    foreach ($pubished_post->posts as $post)
    {
        $_product = wc_get_product($post->ID);
        if ($_product->is_type('variable'))
        {
            // Product has variations
            $has_variable_ids[] = $post->ID;
        }
    }
}


$args = [
    'post_type' => ['product_variation'],
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_parent__in' => $has_variable_ids,
    'meta_query' => [
        [
            'key' => 'attribute_pa_flower-type',
            'value' => $flower_type,
            'compare' => '=',
        ]
    ]
];

$the_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

*Please Note: I have't tested it, but it should work.*

Hope this helps!

Comment: yeah that's works, what I did finally is to get the parent post for each variation and check its status inside the while loop, but i'll change my code to yours because its faster

Comment: I didn't find and WooCommerce function for this so I did so form my WP knowledge.